# Applescript: Copy/Duplicate only if size requirement is met

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

How do I write the condition of duplicating if size requirement is met on applescript?

This is what I have:

```
set src to POSIX path of "path here"
set dst to POSIX path of "path here"
(*Some if statement here to check size of file*)
duplicate files in folder (POSIX file src as alias) to (POSIX file dst as alias)
```

I am trying to make it so it only duplicates if the size of the file is less than some value and I am struggling to figure out the if statement that I need. I was thinking about manually iterating through every file and checking the size and duplicating, however, couldn't figure out the code for that either.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Approximately how many files will be in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't planning on duplicating countless thousands of files, here is a simple script to duplicate files from one folder to another.

First, it generates a list of files in the source folder. It then cycles through each list item and if the file's size is within the range, adds the file to a matching list. When that is complete, it duplicates the matching files to the destination folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
set srcFol to ((path to downloads folder as text) & "here:")
set dstFol to ((path to desktop as text) & "there:")

set everyFile to (get files of folder srcFol as alias list)
set sizedFiles to {}
repeat with aFile in (a reference to everyFile)
    set sz to size of aFile
    if sz is greater than 200000 and sz is less than 299000 then
        set end of sizedFiles to aFile
        set label index of aFile to 4 -- used to highlight matching files during testing
    end if
end repeat

duplicate sizedFiles to dstFol with replacing
end tell
```

NB the 'set label index' line simply puts a colour tag on each file. I use it during testing to highlight the files being duplicated. Comment it out once you confirm everything works. If you don't wish existing files to be overwritten remove the `with replacing`.

If you plan on duplicating folders with lots and lots of files (or with subfolders) then you might want to consider `do shell script` along with something like ditto or rsync.

Answer (score 1):

This following **AppleScript** code allows you to choose a folder to search for the files by size.  It then allows you to choose a destination folder to copy the result of files to.  Then finally, it allows you to enter the file size criteria to search for.

It then will copy the files that meet the search criteria to your chosen destination folder.

```
property searchFolder : missing value
property destinationFolder : missing value

activate
set {fileSize, recursiveSearch} to {text returned, button returned} of ¬
    (display dialog "Search For Files Options:" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
        "The provided example means searching for files greater than" & ¬
        " 10 MB and less than 50 MB." default answer "-size +10M -size -50M" buttons ¬
        {"Cancel", "Search Recursively", "Search"} default button 3 ¬
        with title "Search For Files" with icon 1)

if recursiveSearch = "Search" then
    folderChoices()
    set folderDepth to " -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 "
else if recursiveSearch = "Search Recursively" then
    folderChoices()
    set folderDepth to " -type f -mindepth 1 "
end if

do shell script "find " & searchFolder & folderDepth & fileSize ¬
    & " -exec cp -p {} " & destinationFolder & " \\;"

on folderChoices()
    activate
    set searchFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Choose A Source Folder To Search" with invisibles)
    activate
    set destinationFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Choose A Destination Folder To Place Copied Files" with invisibles)
end folderChoices
```

*I also added the option to search recursively through all folders of your chosen folder.*

[image]

You can also mix different size units like this:

- -size +100k -size -1M (greater than 100 kB and less than 1 MB)
- -size +500M -size -1G (greater than 500 MB and less than 1 GB)
- -size -3M             (less than 3 MB)

[image]